# Is there a replacement for the DPAPI (Data Protection API) in .Net Core for Maui?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, maui, maui-blazor

I am attempting to port an application from .Net Framework 4.7 WPF to .NET Core 6 Maui/Blazor. In the .Net Framework app, I used the DataProtection Api for storing data that could only be decrypted at the User/Machine level. All of the Data Protection info I am finding for .Net Core is ASP.Net Core related. I do not think the ASP.NET libs are available in a plain old Maui app. Is there a replacement for the DPAPI available for this scenario? If not, what are the accepted options in the .NET Core world?

Thanks

Comment: There seems to be a standalone NuGet package for the same purpose although I'm not sure how "AspNetCore" takes part in the equation: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection/

Comment: I have found that .NET Maui has an ISecureStorage / SecureStorage implementation that may do the trick. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like it gives you the encrypted data so you can attach it to a file, which my use case requires. The Learn docs are at url: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/secure-storage?tabs=windows

Comment: The SecureStorage in Maui is close to what I need, but not quite since you lose any stored data on an Uninstall of the app.  My scenario is an RPA app that stores DPAPI encrypted credentials/keys in the bot files, so any user who uses the file only needs to add the creds once per Machine/Logged-in User. This looks like any uninstall of the app or potentially an upgrade would lose the secure data. Otherwise, this could work.

Comment: You could try using [Isloated Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/isolated-storage#secure_access) in addition to protection. Besides, you can also try using [Safe storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=windows).